Which computer companies have been featured on Formula 1 cars?
A number of computer companies have sponsored F1 teams in the past. For example:

Sun Microsystems had their logo on the rear view mirrors of the McLaren MP4/11 (1996) through the MP4-20 (2005).
The DEC logo was on the nose & front wing of the Ferrari 156/85 through the F92A.
(Somewhat new) AMD was featured on the rear wing of the Ferrari F2002 until 2009.
(Even newer) In recent years, both IBM and HP have been sponsors. I'm not sure if they had previous sponsored any teams.

Since this is retrocomputing, I think the cutoff date should probably be sometime before 2005 or so. The company must have had their branding featured on a constructor's car, although due to the existence of prequalifying at the time I don't think they need to have actually started in a GP. As long as they actually showed up.

I’m voting to close this question because Stack Exchange isn’t suited to “list” questions.

@StephenKitt Agreed. Also, it seems to go past computer as most would qualify AMD as a semiconductor company - much like Infineon, main sponsor for Honda ca. 2001.

You may get an answer to this on Sports.SE, but they aren't keen on list questions either.

"list" questions don't bother me. But this is about computer advertising in a very distant way. Computer advertising can have useful Q & A here - e.g., when was xyz type of system first publicly marketed; were all features in a particular ad for a not-quite-ready system ever actually delivered, etc. But this is computing in, literally, name (of company) only - that just doesn't fit "retrocomputing" in my mind.
